# Im trying to code a to-do list but it doesn't work, can someone tell me what's wrong?

Tags: list, button, addeventlistener, appendchild, createelement

im asking for help because when i click the button, nothing appears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>To-do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="planning">What are you planning to do today ?</h1>
  </header>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Go groceries shopping, call Peter, ..." id="taskAdder">
    </li>
    <!-- <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
      <input type="text id="task2>
    </li> -->
  </ul>
  <button id="btn">+</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my html, I have an input where i write my task right after my checkbox input, a list where tasks added will be, and a button under this list that adds the task.

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let list = document.getElementById("list");
let taskAdder = document.getElementById("taskAdder");
let conteur = 2;

btn.addEventListener("click", createNewTask);

function createNewTask() {

    if (taskAdder.value !== '') {
        let newLi = document.createElement("li");
        newLi.id = `liItem${conteur}`;

        let newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
        newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
        newCheckbox.className = "checkbox";
        newCheckbox.id = `checkbox${conteur}`;

        let newInput = document.createElement("input");
        newInput.id = `task${conteur}`;
        newInput.htmlFor = newInput.id;
        newInput.textContent = taskAdder.value;

        list.appendChild(newLi);
        newLi.appendChild(newCheckbox);
        newLi.appendChild(newInput);
        conteur++;

        taskAdder.value = '';
        taskAdder.placeholder = "Go groceries shopping, call Peter, ...";

        } else {
            alert("Please type something you want to do to create a task");
        }
    }
```

Here is my js, i add an eventlistener to my button and tell him to execute the function createNewTask. In this function, i check first if the taskAdder input is empty, if true i alert, if false i create a list item, create a checkbox input and create a text input, i append my list item to my unordered list, then i append my two inputs to my list item. Finally i reset my taskAdder file.

I'm a beginner so excuse me for the quality of my explanation and my code.

I tried to debug, but no bugs are showing, i tried to see if there was typos errors in my code but i think there isn't. As im a beginner i think there is something i missed or something i don't know yet.

Comment: Works for me if I remove the first script element (why do you import the file twice?)

Comment: i didn't saw i imported it twice, thanks knittl

Comment: yeah thx, there was also another error : i created an input and for an input to have a value it must be assigned directly on the site, so i created a label for my checkbox instead.